# prove that $\text{ord}_k(a)\mid \text{ord}_{k+1}(a)$ where $\text{ord}_k(a)$ is the order of a in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}^\ast$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\newcommand{\ordz}[2]{\text{ord}_{#2}(#1)}$

> Prove that $\text{ord}_k(a)\mid \text{ord}_{k+1}(a)$ where $\text{ord}_k(a)$ is the order of a in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}^\ast$

I thought doing it using induction on k:

for k=1: $\ordz gk\mid\left|U_{p}\right|=p-1$
 . Furthermore,$\ordz g{k+1}\mid\left|U_{p^{2}}\right|=p(p-1)$
  but since p is prime the only options for the order of g in $U_{p^{2}}$
  are $p-1,p(p-1)$
  which are both divisble by $\ordz gk$

but for general k I cannot find my way out when I need to calculate $\varphi{(p^k)}$. How can prove the general  step for given k?

Comment: I think you mean $\varphi(p^k)$, not $\varphi(p^k-1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $e$ be the order modulo $p^{k+1}$. Then $a^e\equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$. It follows by a probably familiar result that the order of $a$ modulo $p^k$ divides $e$.

If the result is not familiar, let $d$ be the order of $a$ modulo $p^k$. Then $e=qd+r$ for some $r$ where $0\le r\lt d$. Show that $r=0$.

Comment: Thanks but what's the benfit in looking at the order modulo $p^k$? I can caluclate maybe euler function for $U_{p^k}$ and procceed?

Comment: Don't use the Euler function!

Comment: I think i understand. thanks. p.s: what's bad with euler function?

Comment: Nothing bad. However, let $m$ and $n$ be any integers such that $m$ divides $n$. Then the order of $a$ modulo $m$ divides the order modulo $n$. Here we are looking at the special case $n=p^{k+1}$, $n=p^k$. But same proof as the one I suggested works in general.

Answer (score 0):

$\varphi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}=p^{k-1}(p-1)$, whence $\varphi(p^k)\mid\varphi(p^{k+1})$.